# Correct way to construct .NET Expression to invoke dynamic objects

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, lambda

I need to create a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` that call a dynamic object. The dynamic object can be an `ExpandoObject` or any other `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`.

Consider the following test:

```
var myInstance = DateTime.Now;

var methodInfo = myInstance.GetType().GetMethod("ToUniversalTime");

var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(myInstance), methodInfo);
var expression = Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpression);

Assert.AreEqual(myInstance.ToUniversalTime(), expression.Compile().DynamicInvoke());
```

I need to create an equivalent expression when myInstance is declared like (just as an example):

```
dynamic myInstance = new ExpandoObject();
myInstance.MyMethod = new Func<string>(() => "hello world");
```

I suppose that I need to use `Expression.Dynamic` method (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.dynamic%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). But I don't known how to use it. I have tried to search on google but the only examples that I have found use the `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder` class (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.binder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) that cannot be officially used:

> This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

Using `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder` I can write the code below:

```
dynamic myInstance = new ExpandoObject();
myInstance.MyMethod = new Func<string>(() => "hello world");

var binder = Binder.InvokeMember(
    CSharpBinderFlags.None,
    "MyMethod",
    null,
    this.GetType(),
    new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.Constant, null) });

var methodCallExpression = Expression.Dynamic(binder, typeof(object), Expression.Constant(myInstance));
var expression = Expression.Lambda(methodCallExpression);

Assert.AreEqual(myInstance.MyMethod(), expression.Compile().DynamicInvoke());
```

It this solution correct?

Comment: Yes, this is how I implemented it in CSharpEval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the catch: from my understanding, there is no meaning in making a dynamic call without some kind of `Binder` object.

The binder object represents the rules that are followed for dynamic name resolution:

- Should the match be case-sensitive?
- How should method overloads be resolved?
- What to do if the object is a non-dynamic object?
- What fallbacks do you use?

In other words, the `Binder` object represents the semantics of the calling "language", while `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` represents the semantics of the called object.

So, yes, we are not supposed to use the CSharp Binder object. That can be felt especially when some issues happen that can only be worked around by using the object's internals. However, the alternative is simply to use another, non-framework-provided, `Binder` implementation.

Answer (score -1):

```
  dynamic x = typeof("<<MethodName>>")
            .GetMethod("ToUniversalTime")
            .Invoke(<<Type Of Object>>, new object[] { [Parameter1,]                    
            [Parameter2,....] });
```

in this code "Type" instead from which type of object you have to call method...

specify your method name instead of "MethodName"

and lastly your object instead of "Type of Object"

and if there is no parameter then pass empty array...other wise pass instead of "parameter1,2,and so on.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to construct an expression tree, see Expression class. Your code simply call a methid via reflection.